# How to add shared file or folder to my drive using applescript

Tags: applescript

I want to add shared file or folder on shared with my folder (https://drive.google.com/drive/shared-with-me ) to my drive folder (https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive) using applescript.
I have no idea how to do it. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

do you have the google drive app downloaded to your computer? if so its easy. if not its still possible, though slightly more cumbersome.

you can use this function to click something ona webpage (like the download button on a google drive page)

```
to clickID(theId) 
tell application "Safari"
do JavaScript “document.getElementById('" & theId & "').click();" in document 1
end tell 
end clickID
```

(got that from here: http://cubemg.com/applescript/how-to-click-a-button-on-a-web-page-with-applescript/)

edit: the question has been changed substantially so a loit of what i wrote previously now seems like misguided gibberish. heres what you need to know

**edit:** it appears you cannot right click on the add to my drive button without holding down command while right clicking.

go to the above link and read the instructions, which teach yiou how to 'click a button' on a webpage using applescript.

Or go to the link i posted above and look at the available functions. then right click on the item you wish to click on, select inspect element, and see what information it contains. Based on that information, find a corresponding function.

Ie you click inspect element it might say 'id="piano"'

then you use the clickelementbyid function, with 'piano' as the parameters, the function can be found at the above link.

there is another link on that site that deals with filling out forms, which is what you have to do in order to log in.

Comment: I have the google drive app on my mac, but there is no folder called shared with me.

Comment: I don't want to download a file. I just need to add file.

Comment: what I want to do are 1 Sign in to drive.google.com.
2 On the left, click Shared with me.
3 Click a file.
3 At the top, or from the right-click menu, click Add to My Drive .

Comment: if you download and install the google drive app, all your google drive stuff will be on your computer. Here are pictures of how to get to them. https://www.dropbox.com/s/umw8xkrh7e51t99/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-22%20at%2011.05.21%20AM.png?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/8uwuidiou9vs01v/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-22%20at%2011.05.56%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: the second function i posted lays out the groundwork for how any file can be moved from one location to another, or 'added'

Comment: on any google drive document you can click file then copy, and save the file wherever you like. You can make an applescript to systematically click those items using the function and/or link i posted.

Comment: the link in my original post details the process, but in safari right click and select 'inspect element' on the item you wish the click. after you click inspect element this 'inspector' will appear at the bottom of the screen. In this inspector you will see information about the button you are trying to click, Based on the information youre given you can find the ideal function to use to click that button. the functions are listed on http://cubemg.com/applescript/how-to-click-a-button-on-a-web-page-with-applescript/ (which i already posted in my answer). they list several.

Comment: OK Thank you very much I'll try